# How to emit object to server with key

Tags: javascript, java, socket.io, java-websocket

I'm trying to follow this example in JS and convert it to Java
https://github.com/cryptoqween/cryptoqween.github.io/blob/master/streamer/current/stream.js

This code below is from the document:

```
var subscription = ['5~CCCAGG~BTC~USD', '5~CCCAGG~ETH~USD', '11~BTC', '11~ETH'];
socket.emit('SubAdd', { subs: subscription });
```

So how can i write this in android studio, here is what i have tried

```
String[] subscription = {"5~CCCAGG~BTC~USD", "5~CCCAGG~ETH~USD", "11~BTC", "11~ETH"};
HashMap<String, String[]> maps = new HashMap<>();
Socket mSocket;

maps.put("subs", subscription);
try {
   mSocket = IO.socket("https://streamer.cryptocompare.com/");
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
mSocket.connect();
mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
mSocket.on("m", onData);
```

This is how i emit the item to server:

```
mSocket.emit("SubAdd", maps);
```

And i keep getting error "401~BADFORMAT" from server,
Can someone help me pls.

Comment: I also tried to emit each item with key but it doesn't work either

Comment: Array types are usually suspect in Java. Have you inspected the actual incoming request content, and have you tried using `List<String>`?

Comment: already tried List<String> still the same :((

Answer (score 1):

I'm so silly, This is JSONObject and JSONArray
This code below will work:

```
JSONArray b = new JSONArray();
JSONObject a = new JSONObject();

b.put("5~CCCAGG~BTC~USD", "5~CCCAGG~ETH~USD", "11~BTC", "11~ETH")
a.put(b)

socket.emit("subs",a)
```